# Google Calendar API: New event properties

Tags: google-calendar-api, gdata-api, gdata

I'm developing an Android APP that connects to Google Calendar using [GData API for Google Calendar in Java](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_java.html). So far I've managed to create events but I could only set the title, description and time.

Does anybody know where I can find a reference or a sample with all the parameters I can set to an event?

I leave you some code of what I've achieved so far.

```
CalendarService calendarService = new CalendarService("CalendarAPP");
calendarService.setUserCredentials(<username>, <password>);
URL postUrl = new URL("https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/<GMAIL ACCOUNT>/private/full");
CalendarEventEntry myEntry = new CalendarEventEntry();

myEntry.setTitle(new PlainTextConstruct("Tennis with Beth"));
myEntry.setContent(new PlainTextConstruct("Meet for a quick lesson."));

DateTime startTime = DateTime.now();
DateTime endTime = DateTime.now();
When eventTimes = new When();
eventTimes.setStartTime(startTime);
eventTimes.setEndTime(endTime);
myEntry.addTime(eventTimes);

CalendarEventEntry insertedEntry = connection.getCalendarService().insert(postUrl, myEntry);
```

Thanks in advance.

Mikywan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GData for Google Calendar it's  pretty damn good. For every property you may want to set or get, there is a Getter and a Setter defined. You just have to look for the setter/getter on the event entry that suits the data you want access.

I leave an example of how to show on the console almost all the data you may want to.

Enjoy!

```
private static void showCalendarEventEntry(CalendarEventEntry entry) {
    assert entry != null;
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("START showCalendarEventEntry");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("ID: " + entry.getId());
    System.out.println("TITLE: "+entry.getTitle().getPlainText());
    System.out.println("DESCRIPTION: "+entry.getPlainTextContent());
    System.out.println("LOCATION: "+entry.getLocations().get(0).getValueString());

    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("TIMES");
    if (entry.getTimes().size() > 0) {
        When eventTimes = entry.getTimes().get(0);
        if (eventTimes.getStartTime().isDateOnly()) {
            System.out.println("\tWHEN: ALL DAY");
        } else {
            System.out.println("\tWHEN: TIME");
        } 

        if (entry.getRecurrence() != null)
            System.out.println("\tRECURRENCE: "+entry.getRecurrence().toString()); 

        System.out.println("\tSTART TIME: "+eventTimes.getStartTime());
        System.out.println("\tEND TIME: "+eventTimes.getEndTime());
    }

    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("PARTICIPANTS");
    System.out.println("\t"+(entry.getParticipants().size()) + " PARTICIPANTS");
    if (entry.getParticipants().size() > 0){

        for (int i=0; i<entry.getParticipants().size(); i++) {
            EventWho participant = entry.getParticipants().get(i);
            System.out.println("\t\tPARTICIPANT "+participant.getValueString());
            System.out.println("\t\t\tTYPE: "+participant.getAttendeeType());
            System.out.println("\t\t\tSTATUS: "+participant.getAttendeeStatus());
        }
        if (entry.isGuestsCanInviteOthers())
            System.out.println("\tGUESTS CAN INVITE OTHERS: ");
        if (entry.isGuestsCanModify())
            System.out.println("\tGUESTS CAN MODIFY");
        if (entry.isGuestsCanSeeGuests())
            System.out.println("\tGUESTS CAN SEE GUESTS");
    } 

    //REMINDERS
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("REMINDERS");
    System.out.println("\t"+entry.getReminder().size()+" REMINDERS");
    if (entry.getReminder().size() > 0) {
        for (int i=0; i<entry.getReminder().size(); i++) {
            Reminder reminder = entry.getReminder().get(i);
            System.out.println("\t\tREMINDER "+i);
            System.out.println("\t\t\tMETHOD: "+reminder.getMethod().toString());
            System.out.println("\t\t\tDAYS: "+reminder.getDays());
            System.out.println("\t\t\tHOURS: "+reminder.getHours());
            System.out.println("\t\t\tMINUTES: "+reminder.getMinutes());                
        }
    }

    //VISIBILITY
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("VISIBILITY: "+entry.getVisibility().getValue());

    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("END showCalendarEventEntry");
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------------");
}
```